# Dell Servers - Email notification

Tags: monitoring

We have all Dell servers in our environment.  We want some sort of software (Dell software or 3rd party) that will notify us via email if any hardware failures occur.  What do you recommend?

Comment: Asking for software recommendations are offtopic here, but fortunately not on http://softwarecs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dell OMSA can do e-mail notifications; I don't know how, but I saw some come from a couple of our servers the other day until I told the person setting up those servers to roll them into our monitoring system.

Comment: DOMSA on it's own can not send email. It can send SNMP traps. you need DITA to send emails based on DOMSA events.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, DOMSA (Dell OpenManage Server Administrator) itself can't send email notifications. DITA (Dell IT Assistant) is the management console (management station) for managing servers that have DOMSA (managed system) installed. DITA does support email notifications. DITA has been deprecated, but it's still available for download from the Dell support site. I use it because the Altiris (Symantec) product that has replaced it is too bloated, complicated, confusing, and cumbersome.

You can still download DITA from Dell's web site, although I don't have the link available at the moment.

Comment: This is accurate.  It's been a while since I configured one this way.  We have in the past used the "Alert Management" tab and executed the mail command on our linux servers and that is what I was thinking with my answer.  So no, you can't email (for alerting) directly from Server Administrator but you can send email from the remote access controller and helper applications within SA.  Joe, please edit your post so I can remove my too hasty -1 and accept my apologies.

Comment: NP. You're keeping me on my toes, making sure I always check my answers to make sure they're accurate (which they aren't always although my intention is always to give a good answer).

Comment: And by edit (after rereading sounded a little forceful) I didn't mean change content.  I waited too long to undo my -1 and wanted the opportunity to take it back.

Answer (score 2):

Open Manage Server Administrator will do it.  It has been replaced with an Altiris clone for the 11th gen servers though.  I'm not sure the details on it but it is called DMC or Dell Management Console (I think).  It will do email notification but is kind of klunky.  We use Nagios in-house with snmp checks and a subset of the open manage suite.

Comment: DOMSA on it's own can not send email. It can send SNMP traps. you need DITA to send emails based on DOMSA events.